# PGF of negative multinomial expansion

Tags: probability, generating-functions, multinomial-coefficients, negative-binomial, multinomial-theorem

I have found the formula for the Probability Generating Function of negative multinomial distribution in Definition 8.1 of this chapter (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118445112.stat01250). It is as follows. $$G_x(\boldsymbol{t}) = \left(\mathcal{Q} - \sum^k_{i=1} P_{it_i}\right)^{-n}$$, where $n > 0$, $P_i > 0(i = i, \ldots, k)$, and $\mathcal{Q} - \sum^k_{i=1} P_{i} = 1$. I am still confused with the following:

- What do $\mathcal{Q}$ and $P_i$ mean?
- How can I use this to compute the coefficient of the terms in the series expansion of $\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m \right)^{-n}$, where, $m > 0$?

Comment: It looks like your source had a typo. I'm guessing the $t_i$ should not have been part of the subscript, so the portion inside the parenthesis should have been $\mathcal{Q} - \sum_{i=1}^k P_i t_i$. Also I've only briefly skimmed it, but this might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263942/probability-generating-function-of-a-negative-multinomial-distribution

Comment: @forgottenarrow, it is not clear what the size of a multinomial means in that answer.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by size of a multinomial. That answer seems to be for the case where there are $r+1$ possible events per trial in $\{0,1,\dots,r\}$ and the trials stop after event 0 appears $k$ times.

Comment: Is the work that you linked published or available somewhere else also? Is it open source? I wanted to read your context from the link but I saw that I would have to purchase the paper...

Comment: @NoureddineOuertani, I have shared the screenshots of Section 2.4-5 in the answer which build up to the equation I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

I am using this space to post the content of Section 2.4 which builds up to the equation I have used in the question.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]