# What is the size of a multinomial?

Tags: probability, generating-functions, multinomial-coefficients, negative-binomial, multinomial-theorem

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263942/probability-generating-function-of-a-negative-multinomial-distribution) uses the phrase "multinomial of size".

What is the definition of the **size** of a multinomial? They are using a negative multinomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size is a metric on on an elementary event, which is defined as a sequence of multinomial events before a stopping event occurs. Each multinomial event can have $n$ outcomes where $n \geq 2$. It is not a metric on the number of outcomes of each trial.

Comment: so, the size is the length of the sequence?

Comment: That's how I read it. In the linked question, the answer refers to the "multinomial of size" and this is confusing.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.